# Cisco error 51 on OSX 10.7.4

Tags: mac-osx, cisco-vpn

Cisco VPN client version 4.9.01.0290 does not work on OSX 10.7.4 but it works on 10.7.2. The issue is that x64 are not supported. I am not sure way it is working on another mac with OSX 10.7.2, which is still Lion and it is x64. I tried to reboot in 32bit but it does not work anymore. I tired other clients, including the in-built client but the decrypted shared key have characters that are known to break the key ($ and &).

Any help?

Comment: I discovered that the latest version of Cisco vpn client works in 10.7.2 but not in 10.7.4

Answer (score 2):

[Cisco has EOL'd VPN Client](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/vpndevc/ps5743/ps5699/ps2308/end_of_life_c51-680819.html), and so 10.7 is not fully supported (and never will be). Cisco is recommending migration to [Cisco AnyConnect](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps10884/index.html).

That's the bad news.

The good news is that you should be able to configure the VPN connection directly within OS X without installing VPN Client. The other end will have to provide you connection information and possibly a certificate file, but that should be easy enough. Detailed information can be found in [Cisco's documentation](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-15887).

Comment: Thank you, the IT team of the company I need to connect to said that Cisco Anyconnect does not work.

Comment: Fortunately you probably don't need it. See my updated answer.

Comment: I are right and I new that. I forgot to mention that the secret shared password, which I decrypted, have stupit characters such a & and £ and I read that that kind of shared password do not work with the in-build client and it is not working for me.

Comment: I tried Shimo too but it is not working eigher

Comment: At this point I'd contact the company you're trying to connect to, and have _them_ make it work. They should already have worked out this issue for their own VPN users.

Comment: They only support Windows XP, there even do not I have decrypted the password, they are useless.